# Load latex in comments on mobile app?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, comment, comment-replies, android-app

I have the SE app on Android and latex loads great for questions and answers but never on comments. I figure someone would have mentioned it by now but it's been probably a year or two and I've noticed no change.

I grant that this may not be appropriate as a meta "question" but I don't know where else to put a feature request.

Comment: Perhaps this should be tagged ([meta-tag:android-app]) and ([meta-tag:mathjax])? And from the text of the question, it is not clear to me why it is tagged [comment-replies](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info).

Comment: These posts on the main meta might be related: [Android app doesn't render LaTeX content in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244860/android-app-doesnt-render-latex-content-in-comments) and [Easier mechanism to display MathJax in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256480/easier-mechanism-to-display-mathjax-in-comments).

Comment: This older post is rather similar: [MathJax not displayed in Comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/mathjax-not-displayed-in-comments). (Basically the main difference seems the one of them is intended as a bug-report and the other as a feature request.)

Comment: I had to ask.  Basically you touch the Comment to select it, then select Render MathJax from the dot-dot-dot context menu at upper right on the app.